# WP - Woo - Conditional custom product tags based on category selection

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have 3 Product Categories - CATEGORY-1, CATEGORY-2 and CATEGOTRY-3

I've also created 3 additional custom taxonomies to use as TAGS for each category, these are TAGS-1, TAGS-2 and TAGS-3.

I have edited the Woocommerce single product and created a custom tab. In this tab, I would like to show my custom tags depending on the category selection.

So if the CATEGORY-1 is selected for the product, then I'd like to show the TAGS-1, if CATEGORY-2 is chosen, then I'd like to show TAGS-2 and the same for the last set.

My code currently looks like this:

```
<?php global $post, $product, $woocommerce;

    if ( has_term( 'CATEGORY-1', 'product_cat' ) ) {

        $tags = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'TAGS-1' );

    } elseif ( has_term( 'CATEGORY-2', 'product_cat' ) ) {

        $tags = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'TAGS-2' );

    } elseif ( has_term( 'CATEGORY-3', 'product_cat' ) ) {

        $tags = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'TAGS-3' );     

    }

    return $tags;


    if ( $tags ) : ?>

        <ul id="TAGS-LIST">

            <?php foreach ( $tags as $tag ) : ?>

                <li>

                   <?php $tag_link = esc_url( get_term_link( $tag ) ); ?>

                        <a href="<?php echo $tag_link; ?>" class="TAG-CLASS">
                           <span class="TAG-TEXT-CLASS"><?php echo $tag->name; ?></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                <?php endforeach; ?>

            </ul><!-- #TAG-LIST -->

    <?php endif; ?>
```

But unfortunately, I can't seem to be able to make this working. NO output shows up at all. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The main problem here is `return $tags;`… It just stops the execution code after this.

Comment: I got it working @LoicTheAztec, but the long way around - see my answer below, is there away to shorten that? How to go about the `return $tags;` ?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the product data it's hard to say exactly why. I would put some echo statements in there to try and pinpoint where something unexpected is happening.
eg.

```
<?php global $post, $product, $woocommerce;

if ( has_term( 'CATEGORY-1', 'product_cat' ) ) {

    $tags = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'TAGS-1' );

} elseif ( has_term( 'CATEGORY-2', 'product_cat' ) ) {

    $tags = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'TAGS-2' );

} elseif ( has_term( 'CATEGORY-3', 'product_cat' ) ) {

    $tags = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'TAGS-3' );     

}
echo 'cat = ' . wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID,  'product_cat' );
echo 'tags1 = ' . wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID,  'TAGS-1' );
echo 'tags2 = ' . wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID,  'TAGS-2' );
echo 'tags3 = ' . wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID,  'TAGS-3' );

return $tags;


if ( $tags ) { ?>

    <ul id="TAGS-LIST">

        <?php foreach ( $tags as $tag ) : ?>

            <li>

               <?php $tag_link = esc_url( get_term_link( $tag ) ); ?>

                    <a href="<?php echo $tag_link; ?>" class="TAG-CLASS">
                       <span class="TAG-TEXT-CLASS"><?php echo $tag->name; ?></span>
                    </a>
                </li>

            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </ul><!-- #TAG-LIST -->

<?php } else { echo 'no tags present'; }  ?>
```

Does that help?

Comment: Hi Jo, I am now getting the following error: `Notice: Array to string conversion in xxxxxxxxx/functions.php on line 1020
tags3 = Array` I'm getting this for all of the arrays, tags, tags1, tags2, tags3

Comment: Sounds promising, at least those values aren't null! You might need to change them to make the arrays printable like this: `print_r(wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID,  'product_cat' ), true);`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I just went the very long way around, but while this is working fine now, is there a way to make this whole thing much shorter??

```
<div id="product-tags-wrapper">

       <div class="products-tags-container">

          <?php global $post, $product, $woocommerce;

              if ( has_term( 'CATEGORY-1', 'product_cat' ) ) {

                  $tags = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'TAGS-1' );

                  if ( $tags ) : ?>

                  <ul id="TAGS-LIST">

                      <?php foreach ( $tags as $tag ) : ?>

                         <li>
                            <?php $tag_link = esc_url( get_term_link( $tag ) ); ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo $tag_link; ?>" class="TAG-CLASS">
                            <span class="TAG-TEXT-CLASS"><?php echo $tag->name; ?></span>
                            </a>
                         </li>

                       <?php endforeach; ?>

                   </ul><!-- #TAG-LIST -->

                   <?php endif; ?>

              <?php } elseif ( has_term( 'CATEGORY-2', 'product_cat' ) ) {

                $tags = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'TAGS-2' );

                if ( $tags ) : ?>

                  <ul id="TAGS-LIST">

                      <?php foreach ( $tags as $tag ) : ?>

                         <li>
                            <?php $tag_link = esc_url( get_term_link( $tag ) ); ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo $tag_link; ?>" class="TAG-CLASS">
                            <span class="TAG-TEXT-CLASS"><?php echo $tag->name; ?></span>
                            </a>
                         </li>

                       <?php endforeach; ?>

                   </ul><!-- #TAG-LIST -->

                   <?php endif; ?>

             <?php } elseif ( has_term( 'CATEGORY-3', 'product_cat' ) ) {

                $tags = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'TAGS-3' );

                if ( $tags ) : ?>

                  <ul id="TAGS-LIST">

                      <?php foreach ( $tags as $tag ) : ?>

                         <li>
                            <?php $tag_link = esc_url( get_term_link( $tag ) ); ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo $tag_link; ?>" class="TAG-CLASS">
                            <span class="TAG-TEXT-CLASS"><?php echo $tag->name; ?></span>
                            </a>
                         </li>

                       <?php endforeach; ?>

                   </ul><!-- #TAG-LIST -->

                   <?php endif; ?>   

              <?php } ?>    

       </div>

    </div>
```